# 1st law of thermodynamics mcq question

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

Given the following question: [image]

could someone explain how A is correct and D is wrong? 
I'm a little confused. Since its a closed cycle shouldnt there be no energy lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A and D are ambiguous. Your interpretation, that "energy lost or gained" means overall change in internal energy, does indeed lead to A being wrong and D being right. I suppose that another interpretation might be that the gas loses energy in the form of heat, equal to the work done on it over the cycle, leading to A being right and D being wrong. Not your fault.

Comment: Oh, ok! That explains it :)